# eclipse tomcat: how can i deploy a java tomcat project to a directory without having tomcat installed?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm writing a tomcat project to be executed by red5 so I don't have any tomcat servers available. how can I deploy the project to a specific directory that I choose so it will copy the classes to the WebContent directory properly ?

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build a War.  The build process should take care of this for you.  You should be able to deploy the war (web archive) file to Tomcat without worrying about copying class files.  This is a much more reliable method of deploying applications.